# Are there more relative directions?

Tags: synonyms, deixis, direction

6 common relative directions are front, back, left, right, up, and down. Are there single word names for relative directions between those 6 directions (as in another word for a direction between front and right, or front-right, without being a compound word or containing any hyphens and such)?

Comment: No, there aren't. This isn't laid out like a compass; it's a projection of the human body and its motions. Take a look at [Fillmore's Deixis Lectures](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html); the first two should answer your question and give you more to think about.

Comment: 'Front' is different because it is not a direction. It is a position, like 'top' and 'bottom'. The direction is 'forward'.

Comment: "uphill" implies both forward and up. You would never use "uphill" of purely vertical motion. Likewise "downhill".

Comment: Of course in certain contexts and with appropriate elision things like: at your six, and by extension, “at your 10” or “at your 2” could be used.

Comment: I'd be surprised if such terms existed in *any* language.

Comment: Do you mean “relative” to mean relative to a person's reference frame, or relative any other object? **Catercorner** is a single word for a relative direction, meaning *diagonally opposite* to an object

Comment: https://maritime.org/doc/fleetsub/sonar/img/fig10d.jpg

Comment: https://deckskills.tripod.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/points_system.jpg

Answer (score 3):

A common way to refer to more discrete relative directions is by using the clock face analogy. You consider the person to be at the center of a 12-hour clock, facing the 12 at the top. Then "3 o'clock" refers to something to their right, "6 o'clock" is directly behind them, and "9 o'clock" means on their left.

If you've ever heard military people refer to an enemy being "on their six", it comes from this -- it means the enemy is coming at them from behind. They'll also say "I've got your six", meaning that they're protecting the rear of a comrade.

Answer (score 2):

There are many terms of relative direction that are in between the six canonical directions you give (plus some variations on those six). Some apply to movement of the speaker towards and others terms are a direction without implied movement.

- For [right](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right), [left](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/left), [next to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/next), there are:

  - [sharp](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charp) left, sharp right - used only as a noun "Go to the 3-way intersection and take a sharp right"
  - [bear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear) left, bear right - used only as a verb "Go to the fork in the road and bear left"
  - [catty-cornered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catty-corner), kitty cornered (and varieties - US English only) - diagonally across from this is usually an absolute direction, at an intersection with no speaker involved, it is this is diagonally oriented and is quasi-relative to the speaker - that is, at an inters. But it can be used for any diagonal relation "They're sitting catty-cornered to you at the round table" (= they are neither exactly to your left/right, nor directly across but somewhere between)
- in front of, behind, back - there are no words for intermediate directions unless you say "catty-cornered behind"
- up, down, above, below, ahead behind

  - [uphill](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uphill), [downhill](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downhill), steeply (no word for 'with a slight rise/fall'). There's no term for up or down diagonally to your left or right except for the combination "uphill to your right" which is not a set phrase.

The above are mostly transparent combinations of words. They are easily understood compositions of words (except for catty-cornered).

As mentioned in comments, there are some technical situations that are not as transparent:

- Flying a plane or a boat: turning movement, twisting along an axis. These aren't an intermediate static angle between straight and perpendicular, but they do describe relative motion along the continuum.

  - [roll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll) - to twist going forward
  - [pitch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch) - to lean forward or back
  - [yaw](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll) - to spin like a top
- clock directions - the hours on a clock face are the left/right/front/back directions.

  - for example "I got your six" means someone is taking care of what's behind you. One can then say in that vein "watch your four" meaning to be concerned about the direction behind to the right. It is not a set phrase but is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. But you can use a compass (north, west, northwest, etc.) and if you're really curious about strange directions, you could use the words "ana" and "kata" (which have been used to suggest analogues to forward and backward in the 4th dimension).

Really, what actual sentence or situation requires the words that you want?

Comment: Compass directions aren't really relative though unless you consider them as being relative to the planet. If you face south the house to the west is to your right but if you face east the house is behind you. Port, starboard, afore and abaft are relative to an individual vessel but if you face aft port is on your right so the nautical directions are not relative to anyone on board.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but as far as I know, only nautical ones.

If you're on a boat, there are four more relative directions: *port* is towards the left side of the boat, and *starboard* is towards the right side of the boat. *Forward* is towards the front end (the bow) of the boat, and *aft* is towards the back of it (the stern).

These differ from *left, right, front,* and *back*, as they are with respect to the boat and not to the passenger. If you are facing *aft,* then *port* is *right* and *starboard* is *left*.

Answer (score 0):

There are some trivial cases:

- **straight** lies between left and right.
- **level** lies between up and down.

There are also terms that describe rotational movement about an axis, such as **clockwise** and **counterclockwise**.  If these are admitted as descriptions of motion, then **spiral** should be considered as a movement that lies between a pure rotation and a pure linear movement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

These are not "common directions", they are labels that can be applied to a three dimensional coordinate system if you assume an observer with an arbitrary position and orientation, and they will indicate which direction something moves and along which axis something lies. As there are only three axes there will only ever need to be sets of three when it comes to words like this. In other words, **NO**.

Answer (score 0):

There is one direction you did not account for, “within”. This becomes a conceptual direction in 4-Dimensional theoretical geometry.

To try to understand, in 2D everything has a length and a width on a single plane, but lacks depth. In 3D, we add a second plane as a cross section, depth (forward and backward). 4D adds a theoretical inner plane. This is an extensively complex theory, so please see the following link for further explanation: [Wikipedia: Fourth Dimensional Space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space)

As for additional, non-hyphenated phrases, there are additional terms such as; bisect, tangent, perpendicular, parallel. These terms can inform specific relative dimensionality based on angles and planes.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, but as compound words

I have encountered the expressions “[half left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill_commands#Turning_motions)” or “[slight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slight) right” which mean, respectively, forward and left at about 45 degrees and forward and a little to the right.